# Sorting drop down lists in value relation widget in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, widget, sorting, qgis-custom-widgets

I have some attributes in my data and want to enable the user to pick values from drop-down lists. The values of the drop-down list change depending on the chosen value of the previous field(s). The values for the drop-down come from different domain tables.

The task I can accomplish perfectly with Value Relation Widget. However, it works only when I choose the same attribute `"Key column"` and `Value Column`. When I do that, I can only sort the drop-down alphabetically. In my domain table, I have a column for sorting and I would like to use that. When I choose that column then the hierarchy won't work anymore.

So it works if it is set like this

[image]

[image]

Here is how the drop-down works but alphabetically ordered

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQsAc.gif]

My attempt to order them differently

[image]

[image]

As you can see here

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrb1q.gif]

the values for `L_PZART_KTG` is sorted by SORT attribute, but the hierarchy won't work anymore. Nothing will be listed for `L_GZGRP_KTG`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the fact that I am poorly versed in German - I created a separate data set in English, which should be understandable to all readers of the site.

In order to sort the data in the QGIS drop-down list according to a manually defined order, you need to have the following fields in the tables.

Table 1:

1. `table1_sort` - manual sorting of rows.
2. `table1_type` - groups.

Table 2:

1. `table2_sort` - manual sorting of rows.
2. `table2_type` - groups.
3. `table2_objects` - objects.
4. `table2_sort` - The field that contains the same values as the `table1_sort` field.

New data will be entered in `Table 3`. It should contain the following fields:

1. `types` - groups.
2. `objects` - objects.

Now go to `Table 3` field paramaters and set the Widget type to `Value Relation`.

Now select the `types` field and set the following parameters for it:

1. `Layer` -> `Table 1`
2. `Key column` -> `table1_sort`
3. `Value column` -> `table1_type`

Now select the `objects` field and set the following parameters for it:

1. `Layer` -> `Table 2`
2. `Key column` -> `table2_sort`
3. `Value column` -> `table2_objects`
4. `Filter expression` -> `current_value('types') = "table1_sort"`

Now you may try to enter your data with the Drop-down list (with manual sorting):

[image]
<== (click to watch)